# Power Grid Deluxe - Discard Power plant in market

Tags: power-grid

I need clarification on a rule in Power Grid Deluxe

> If, at any time during the game, there is a power plant in the current market with a number equal to or lower than the number
>   of cities any player has, immediately remove it from the game and replace it with a new power plant from the power plant
>   stack. It is also possible that newly drawn power plants must be immediately discarded and a new card drawn. As usual,
>   rearrange the power plants in ascending order. This rule does not affect power plants owned by players.

If I understand correctly, let's say I got 5 cities. Therefore all power plant from the power market and the deck that can power 5 cities or less will be discard? By that matter when the game enter in step 2 where a player has more than 6 cities, there is not power plant left to be bought?

Comment: This rule gets forgotten a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is not referring to the number of cities the plant can power.  It is referring to the number of the plant -- the unique number that you use for ordering the plants in the market.

Comment: So you talk about the minimun bidding price?

Comment: @MathieuL Yes, the minimum bidding price.